# How to fix error of inserting data into table

Tags: mysql

```
insert into task (id primary key auto_increment, Name varchar(45) not null, phone int not null, state varchar(45), city varchar(45)
values (2,'jay', 33, 'luck', 'UP');
```

Comment: You don't put the datatypes into an `INSERT` query. Those are only used in `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I hope this is just made up SQL and not something you found in a MySQL tutorial. If this syntax existed, it would imply that columns do not have a fixed data type. If that feature existed then you'd have Excel, not a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up the syntax of `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO`. They should be separate operations.

```
CREATE TABLE task (
    id primary key auto_increment, 
    Name varchar(45) not null, 
    phone int not null, 
    state varchar(45), 
    city varchar(45)
);

INSERT INTO task (id, Name, phone, state, city)
VALUES (2,'jay', 33, 'luck', 'UP');
```

It's possible to do them in a single query using a `SELECT` query as the source of the data after the column specifications:

```
CREATE TABLE task (
    id primary key auto_increment, 
    Name varchar(45) not null, 
    phone int not null, 
    state varchar(45), 
    city varchar(45)
) AS
SELECT 2,'jay', 33, 'luck', 'UP';
```